# Difference between PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK and ACK in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, omnipay

im using laravel 5 with omnipay/paypal to make some express chekouts.

everything seems good except that in my paypal response i want to know why i have two ACK vars, because some tutorials on the web use it to verify if the payment is accepted or not...

The problem:

On the first time i click on "Pay" im redirected and i have:

```
["ACK"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
["PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
```

Then, if i reload my page i have:

```
["ACK"]=>
  string(18) "SuccessWithWarning"
["PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]=>
  string(67) "A successful transaction has already been completed for this token."
```

My question:

What is the difference between ACK and PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK ?

When paypal say you to use ACK to handle errors : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#id84fb96ff-148f-421c-8cde-b9f9583091ca

Thanks

Comment: `ACK` is the acknowledgement status of the transaction overall ... however PayPal can process several (up to 10) payments in a single transaction. e.g. Say it was a "build your own package holiday" website where you could book your plane tickets, hotel, whatever and pay **each** of those companies individually with one transaction... the `PAYMENTINFO_[0-9]_ACK` values represent the acknowledgement statuses for each of those individual payments.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i helped me guy!